# NHibernate: Saving stops when hitting a unique constraint

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'd like to save a list of stores into the database using NHibernate. However, there is a unique constraint on each store, causing the save to stop when a store triggers the constraint.

```
try
{
    _storeRepository.Save(stores);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
finally
{
    session.Commit();
}
```

In accordance with to the code above, all stores before the unique constraint is hit are saved, but not the ones after. How can I fix this without having to loop the whole list and check for duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules are:

- *Never* catch sql (or NH) Exceptions in the transaction.
- in case of an error, *always* rollback to whole stuff
- in case of an error, *always* destroy the session.

The NH session cache gets out of synch and you can't use it anymore. So "finally commit" is a very bad thing.

You need to make sure that you don't violate any database constraint in your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the `SaveOrUpdate` so NHibernate updates the entity if one with the given entity is found in the database.

Comment: This does not really help to cope with unique constraints - except in the case when the same object is inserted twice.